# FFmpeg and Android encoding issue

Tags: java, android, encoding, ffmpeg

I compiled ffmpeg for Android. The executable works from the device terminal and I can do normal video operations. I am trying to join 2 mpeg files captured using the camera at the command line on the device.

First I Capture 2 videos using the camera and save to sdcard, one.mpeg and two.mpeg. Then I do:

```
 ffmpeg -i one.mpeg onenew.mpeg
 ffmpeg -i twompg.mpeg twonew.mpeg
```

(if i dont do the above 2 commands then it doesnt work at all)

```
 cat onenew.mpeg twonew.mpeg > joined.mpeg
 ffmpeg -i joined.mpeg -acodec copy -vcodec copy final.mpeg
```

The output (final.mpeg) doesnt play on the device but if i copy to my linux desktop it opens up and plays fine. I tested final.mpeg on a 2.3.3 device and a 2.3.6 device.

Anyone know why the device would fail to play the video file?

**UPDATE** 
My friend tested the video on a device running 3.0, the default player never played the video however 'moboplayer' did, I need it to play on the default player though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/faq.html#How-can-I-concatenate-video-files_003f

read sect 3.14.2 in the above link. Lots of work has been done on concatenating media files in an ffmpeg env on linux and it should not really be any different on your android device.

running ffmpeg in terminal on a phone should be just like running in linux ( just like the samples doing cat in the faq )

Test it on linux
then
the same expressions should run on your android device.

You just need to get a filetype suitable for concatenation then use the F-system to cat the files.

Comment: Ive tried all this, mpeg is suitable for concatenation and it plays on linux, it also plays on the device with MXPlayer and Moboplayer, just NOT the default video player which is the same as normal sdk VideoView. The default player is lacking something but I cant seem to figure out what it is :s

Comment: wild guess , maybe the android player is looking for a mov-atom that is not in the right place. I really dont think its something like that. If it plays elsewhere, the android media player should handle it. Maybe u can get additional logging from the android media classes in order to see the stagefright codecs that are in use?

Comment: ok ill try open the file progrmatically in an app and see what errors i can catch

Comment: maybe ICS and JB media players are not that good with all the containers/codecs handled by those other legacy unix players?  Up thru ICS on android , there were lots of android forum  complaints about this or that not playing in the media player..